# Setting Page Title Through $.GET JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, title

Morning People

I have a ajax heavy site. I have read blogs and articles on how they set the page **Title** when ajax calls.

From what I know, they made another request to the server to request for the **Title** or some other methods.

So I came out with my own method/structure. Instead of $.load, I use $.get JSON dataType.

example of JSON data from response (just example):

```
response = {
    success: ...,
    title: ..., //i will use document.title = response.title
    html: ...
```

FYI, I only replace the `<div id="contentHolder">` within the `<body>`

I am planning to implement this method in every ajax request (load content only, not POST).

my question is, is this a correct way to go with? if no, what's your recommended method?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a technically correct solution. If SEO is a consideration however, then you might have to find [better alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142704/ajax-seo-quick-question).

Answer (score 0):

when your json look like =`{"success":true,"title":"My Title","html":"My html content for page"}`

```
get_data();
function get_data(){
    $.getJSON('json-url',function(data){
document.title=data['title'];
        });
}
```